# Workng of LME model used for a set of category variable(s) and a continuous variable?

Tags: linear-regression, data-science-model, linear-algebra

LME models are being used to analyze the effect of continuos data and category data. Is 
this model  appropriate for checking the effect of two independent variables - one with continuous values and another with  nominal category (0, 1) on a dependent  variable? These models, it seems,  use the term random effects for category variables in the linear-mixed effect model. I wish I could get details how the regression coefficients are obtained and combined into the continuous variables effect  to predict the effect on Y dependent variable.

Comment: Consider preparing two separate models,  one regression model for the independent continuous variable and another classification model for the second independent variable with binary output. Please note,  you will need to prepare train data for both model separately.

Comment: I am using the concept of independent  variables which of course  is not related  with correlated variables.

Comment: Would you define train data

Comment: I am here to say Mixed models. MIXED MODELS HAVE been illusively worked out on the basis of mathematical statistics- fixed  or random .

Comment: Split this problem into two- one for regression and another for classification. Mixed model might not perform well, given the target variables of completely different nature. ** Training data** for regression model may exclude categorical target variable ( but if the business problem does not get impacted, I would like to include the left out target variable as independent variable for each). Follow the same for classification problem. Please run and share the accuracy and score for further discussion.